# Service_KMS.exe Trojan

Tags: virus-removal

I found out recently that my computer is afflicted with the Service_KMS.exe Trojan. I detected the Trojan with Avast Free Antivirus. After running a boot-scan Avast deleted the files associated with this Trojan. After a day, the Trojan was detected again. I ran another boot-scan with Avast and the process repeated. The Trojan is still there.

Current Problems:

- Computer has drastically slowed down
- Computer Shutsdown/Restarts/Logs Off
- Computer Freezes temporarily and either unfreezes or shutsdown/restarts

I began to research the Trojan and it says that it is very dangerous. I have tried the methods so far in this article; however, I was not able to locate the files after selecting *Show All Hidden Files* http://www.removewindowsspyware.com/fixerror-exe/service_kms.exe.html

Thank you for your time

Comment: We really aren't the best place for virus removal advice. Take your machine to a trained technician or ask the folks at a virus removal forum.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Virus. That is the Scheduled service to run every time you log in to your windows to keep your windows and Microsoft Office programs suit's licenses activated. the service is made by programs like kmspico, KMSnano or KMSauto.net. if you're willing to stop using those programs you can go to "program files" folder in your C drive to remove them. hope that helps.

Comment: I know that, but why does my antivirus detect it as a threat. I used malwarebytes and it too detected it as a threat.

Comment: well if you know that you also should know that such antivirus programs detect keygens, cracks, patches etc as virus by mistake because they can do what is not allowed. by the way i use the Kaspersky internet security 2015 and it never showed any warning about that service. i'm wondering whether the program is so smart or they're supporting their Russian WZor!:)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a virus. the KMS Activators don't create Service_KMS.exe...

Good tutorial here: http://www.computerimprovment.com/exe-file-error/service_kms.exe-fix-35646/

Comment: Do you know if their listed program will actually remove the Service_KMS.exe

Comment: The link is broken :(